# difficulty calculating angle of a point on a circle

Tags: c++, visual-c++, geometry

I'm having a bit of trouble with the geometry for a function I'm writing. I have a class that contains various sprites. This container class needs to be able to move, rotate, and scale while keeping all the child sprite's relative position, rotation, and scale intact.

I'm running into issues when rotating the container. The angle calculated by atan2 seems to be random. I wrote a simple console application that does and outputs the math behind a function I'm using (it's hard to properly show the code, as it relies on various outside sources). I did this to make sure it wasn't another part of the code causing my error. But my results are the same with the console application. Here is the code (it's stand-alone. you can easily run it)

```
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

  int main()
    {
        float containerX = 0;
        float containerY = 0;

        float childX = 10;
        float childY = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <= 360; i += 36)
        {
            float radius = sqrt(pow(containerX - childX, 2) + pow(containerY - childY, 2));
            float angle = atan2 (containerY - childY, containerX - childX);

            float newAngle = angle + (i / 180.0 * 3.14);

            childX = containerX + radius * cos(newAngle);
            childY = containerY + radius * sin(newAngle);

            std::cout << "New angle: " << newAngle * 180.0 / 3.14 << " New Position: " << childX << ", " << childY << std::endl;

        }

        while(1!=2) {} // This line is so I can read the console output

        return 0;
    }
```

My output is as follows:

```
New angle: 180.091 New Position: -10, -8.74228e-007
New angle: 36 New Position: 8.09204, 5.87528
New angle: -72.0913 New Position: 3.08108, -9.51351
New angle: 216 New Position: -8.10139, -5.86238
New angle: 179.909 New Position: -9.99995, 0.0318542
New angle: 179.817 New Position: -9.99988, 0.0477804
New angle: 215.726 New Position: -8.12931, -5.8236
New angle: 287.635 New Position: 3.00522, -9.53775
New angle: 395.543 New Position: 8.15704, 5.78469
New angle: 179.27 New Position: -9.99897, 0.143339
New angle: 359.178 New Position: 9.99846, -0.175189
```

I know that the problem has something to do with me calculating the angle with atan2, since if I just convert i to radians (i is iterating through degrees 0 and 360 in increments of 36) and pass that to cos and sin, I get points in order around the circle. If I use my "newAngle" variable though, I get random points around the circumference of the circle (bottom left, rop right, near bottom left, left of circle, right of circle, etc)

Thanks for reading this. I really appreciate it. I'm totally stuck. Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Try writing a test program that performs your math for various increments.  It may be easier to see your problem.

Comment: @ZacHowland I had it output the calculated angles, but there doesn't seem to be any pattern to it. However, when I have it just calculate the angle it's at reletive to the container and set itself to that angle, it jumps back and forth between it's original position and the exact opposite position on the sprite. So the only line that I imagine could be giving me trouble is "atan2(yPos - childPos.second, xPos - childPos.first);">
(the output is 0,0,0,180.091,0,0,0,180.091,0,0,0,180.91 Each itteration I had it print the result of atan2 and move the sprite to where cos and sin said it should be)

Comment: I think `atan2` returns a value in the range [-pi, pi]. Are you expecting [0, 2pi]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float angle = atan2 (containerY - childY, containerX - childX);
float newAngle = angle + (i / 180.0 * 3.14);
```

In the first line, you're getting the new angle. In the second line, you're not just adding 36 degrees, instead you're adding `i` degrees, so in every iteration the code is adding an increasing angle to the *new* angle which itself is already increasing, hence the sporadic behavior.

Two different solutions:

1) Replace the first line with

```
float angle = 3.14159; // allow the loop to add to it
```

or

2) Change the `i` to a `36` in the line

```
float newAngle = angle + (36 / 180.0 * 3.14);
```

Don't do both! Choose one.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you so much! I just need to calculate the angle relative to the container whenever the sprite inside moves. It'll save on the amount of calculations per second AND it makes my code work finally. Thank you! I've been working on this problem for days and I don't know if I ever would have figured that out!

Answer (score 2):

> float angle = atan2 (containerY - childY, containerX - childX);

Make it

> float angle = atan2 (childY - containerY, childX - containerX);

As originally written, you are flipping the child coordinates around the center of rotation on every iteration (in other words, adding an extra 180 degrees offset). You could see this easily if you don't adjust the angle at all: `float newAngle = angle;`. Your coordinates would oscillate between -10 and 10.

Comment: Ah ok. In my experimenting I noticed that it would jump back and forth between opposite sides when I passed just the angle. But I thought it was part of the problem that caused it to spin out of control. Those were two separate issues. You helped me solve a separate problem I didn't know I had XD Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hinted at it in my comment, but this is how you could have broken down your issue to see the problem:  http://ideone.com/nTGXuv

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

std::pair<float, float> rotate(std::pair<float, float> origin, std::pair<float, float> start, unsigned int degrees)
{
    std::pair<float, float> diff = std::make_pair(start.first - origin.first, start.second - origin.second);
    float currentAngle = ::atan2(diff.second, std::abs(diff.first));
    float newAngle = currentAngle + (degrees / 180.0 * 3.1415926539);
    float radius = std::sqrt(diff.first * diff.first + diff.second * diff.second);
    float cosAngle = ::cos(newAngle);
    float sinAngle = ::sin(newAngle);
    float x = origin.first + radius * cosAngle;
    float y = origin.second + radius * sinAngle;
    return std::make_pair(x, y);
}

int main() 
{
    std::pair<float, float> origin = std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0);
    std::pair<float, float> start = std::make_pair(1.0, 0.0);
    const unsigned int degrees = 45;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 360; i += degrees)
    {
        std::pair<float, float> newPos = rotate(origin, start, i);
        std::cout << "Rotated to " << i << " degrees: (" << newPos.first << ", " << newPos.second << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```